# Execution order of Maven profile task and goal differs on version 3.3.9 and 3.2.5

Tags: maven

I have a multiple module Maven project where one of the module's POM defined several profiles which copy some configuration file to the `target/classes` dir:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <!-- Copy common resources that are shared in all environments -->
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resources</goal>
                        <goal>testResources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>conf/</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<!-- Copy environment specific resources according to profile used -->
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <testResources>
                <testResource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources/conf/dev</directory>
                </testResource>
            </testResources>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources/conf/dev</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>rct</id>
        <build>
            <testResources>
                <testResource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources/conf/rct</directory>
                </testResource>
            </testResources>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources/conf/rct</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prd</id>
        <build>
            <testResources>
                <testResource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources/conf/prd</directory>
                </testResource>
            </testResources>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources/conf/prd</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

The directory `src/main/resources` in this module contains the following files :

```
02/06/2016  11:15    <DIR>          com
02/06/2016  11:07    <DIR>          conf
02/06/2016  11:19               857 mybatis-config.xml
```

The `conf` directory contains some environment separated files. The thing bizarre is that the result of command `mvn clean validate -Pdev` (executed from the root project) is different while executed on Maven 3.3.9 and Maven 3.2.5:

Result after executed on local machine with Maven 3.3.9:

```
02/06/2016  18:01    <DIR>          com
02/06/2016  18:01               857 mybatis-config.xml
```

Result after executed on Jenkins (don't have other version of Maven installed on local, I believe this doesn't affect the result since Maven 3.3.9 on Jenkins works gives the same result as on local) with Maven 3.2.5:

```
02/06/2016  11:08               144 database.properties
02/06/2016  12:38             1 062 log4j.xml
```

As you see, with Maven 3.3.9, the resource filtering in the `validate` phase worked and tasks in profile was not executed, while on Maven 3.2.5 it just did the inverse. I wonder how would this happen. Is there a bug in Maven concerning this issue?

Comment: First what i see is that you are trying to run the `validate` which does not trigger the resources copying...cause maven-resources-plugin is by default bound to `preccess-resources` have you see the execution of maven-resources-plugin during the run Why are you binding resources plugin to `validate`life cycle phase? Apart from that: Do you have a full working example (for example on GitHub)...

Comment: @khmarbaise I created a demo project on github [stackoverflow-37597528](https://github.com/qingl97/stackoverflow-37597528) I did run `mvn clean validate -X` on the two version of maven, and made a diff of the output. It shows that on 3.2.5, even `<filtering>true</filtering>` is turned on explictly, maven doesn't turn it on really when running.